# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape , on an image

Tags: python, spyder

I would like to add an image, in order to execute a Fourier transform on the image. Here is my code that has the syntax fault at imageio.imread

img1 = imageio.imread("C:\Users\Arnold Bailie.spyder-py3\spyder.lock\einstein.jpg")

Comment: Use raw strings. `img1 = imageio.imread(r"C:\Users\Arnold Bailie.spyder-py3\spyder.lock\einstein.jpg")`